# Example of Integrate applying a numerical evaluation N

Tags: numerical-integration

Here is a minimal example:

```
Integrate[(a[1] + x)^2, {x, 1., 2.}]
```

> ```
> 2.33333 + 3. a[1.] + 1. a[1.]^2
> ```

The problem is that `a[1]` has been turned into `a[1.]`, which is essentially different. A stranger result can be generated from

```
Integrate[(a[1] + x)^2, {x, 1., b}]
```

> ```
> -0.333333 + 0.333333 b^3 + 1. b^2 a[1] + 1. b a[1]^2 + 0.333333 a[1]^3 - 
> 1. a[1.] - 1. a[1.]^2 - 0.333333 a[1.]^3
> ```

That is, part of the result uses `a[1]` and another part uses `a[1.]`.

Question: how to stop this behaviour and why is it happening?

Comment: Artur, I noticed that you had extra bytes when copy/paste some code from _Mathematica_ to _Chrome_ (I guess?). If so there is a _Mathematica_ palette fixing this issue when copying any text (input/output) from _Mathematica_.

Comment: Hi Oska, yes you are right thanks for noticing. Which Mathematica palette can I use to stop these extra bytes?

Comment: You might take a look at [this page](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32/1356) and [this comment](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16877879#16877879). (It's not "officially" updated yet).

Comment: Please tell me if you need assistance, there is a chat for that.

Comment: I also can not reproduce your second example -- what version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a useful attribute, `NHoldFirst` whose purpose is to protect the function from exactly that. So setting:

```
SetAttributes[a, NHoldFirst];
```

and then evaluating the integral works the way you want:

```
Integrate[(a[1] + x)^2, {x, 1., 2.}]
(*2.33333 + 3. a[1] + 1. a[1]^2*)
```

The relevant example from the documentation cites "indexed" functions that are otherwise evaluated numerically (spherical harmonics, elliptic etc) but whose first argument needs to stay an integer.

As per Michael E2's comment, if you want to protect more than just the first of your function's arguments from `N` then `NHoldAll` is the attribute you need.

Comment: +1. There's also `NHoldAll`.  It nice to be reminded that while *we* might think of `a[1]` as an indexed parameter, *M* treats it just like function.

Comment: thanks - yep I added that in the answer now.

Comment: nice solution, yet it is not obvious why `Integrate` applies `N` to the result in the first place.

Comment: Thanks - It's cause the limits have been expressed in machine precision arithmetic

Comment: I see that, I mean its not obvious that should cause the entire resulting expression to be evaluated numerically.

Comment: I was always under the impression that that's what machine precision did to `Integrate`. Check out `Integrate[Cos[x], {x, 1, 2}]` vs `Integrate[Cos[x], {x, 1., 2}]` for instance.

Comment: Thats different. The numeric x makes things that depend on x numeric as expected.  There is no reason for `Integrate` to numericize the constant.  Anybody thinks this makes sense explain why `Integrate[a[1] x , {x, 0, 1.}]` leaves the constant alone while `Integrate[a[1] + x , {x, 0, 1.}]` evidently applies `N` to it..

Comment: Now I sat down and played with it, you are right: this makes absolutely no sense at all to me!

Answer (score 1):

First, I did not get same result as your answer. I got numerical values in all terms.

```
int = Integrate[(a[1] + x)^2, {x, 1., b}]
```

MMA 9:

```
   (* -0.333333 + 0.333333 b^3 - 1. a[1.] + 1. b^2 a[1.] - 1. a[1.]^2 + 
     1. b a[1.]^2 + 5.55112*10^-17 a[1.]^3 *)
```

MMA 10:

```
(*-0.333333 (1. + a[1.])^3 + 0.333333 (b + a[1.])^3*)
```

(Note: if you expand result from MMA 10, the last term in result of MMA 9 vanish)

in both cases if I use Rationalize, here is what I got:

```
Rationalize[int]
```

MMA 9

```
(*-0.333333 + b^3/3 - 1. a[1] + b^2 a[1] - 1. a[1]^2 + b a[1]^2 + 
 5.55112*10^-17 a[1]^3*)
```

MMA 10:

```
(*-(1/3) (1 + a[1])^3 + 1/3 (b + a[1])^3*)
```

(Note: quit interesting to see that MMA 10 can give more accurate and compact form result as compare to MMA 9)

Comment: I don't know what happened but you seem to have posted the same answer three times. You've deleted one but there's still two left.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what happened to my computer. I have already deleted the extra answer :)